Iterating every value from variable in Octopus under helm upgrade step- Raw Values YAML
I am having issues iterating values from the variable and substituting in next line and generating output.
FROM OCTOPUS DOCS: https://octopus.com/docs/projects/variables/variable-filters
Numbers:
#{each number in MyNumbers}
 - #{number}
#{/each}

Objects:
#{each item in MyObjects}
    #{item.Key}: #{item.Value.Price}
#{/each} 

VARIABLES given in Octopus:
USER_ENV: QA - tagged with QA env
USER_ENV: UAT - tagged with UAT env
CLIENTS_QA: CLIENTONE, CLIENTTWO, CLIENTTHREE
yaml written in octopus under Raw Value YAML:
    someConfig:
      #{each client in CLIENTS_QA | Split ','}
      #{USER_ENV}#{client}: yes
      #{/each}

I want the output to be something like: - if ran for QA
someConfig:
  QACLIENTONE: yes
  QACLIENTTWO: yes
  QACLIENTTHREE: yes

How do I make the above work? I am pretty sure that it is not taking the value for "client" in -
#{each client in CLIENTS_QA | Split ','}


Here's a working example using a Kubernetes deployment so you can see the environment variables on the deployed container. I have loosely based it on the scenario you provided.
Variables



Name
Value




USER_ENV
QA


CLIENTS_QA
CLIENTONE,CLIENTTWO,CLIENTTHREE



Inline Yaml for the step
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        #{each client in CLIENTS_QA}- name: #{USER_ENV}#{client}
          value: yes
        #{/each}

This will result in the following environment variables
QACLIENTONE: yes
QACLIENTTWO: yes
QACLIENTTHREE: yes

Key points

Replace #{each client in CLIENTS_QA | Split ','} with #{each client in CLIENTS_QA}

The Octopus variable substituter automatically iterates over and parses items in string arrays. Under the hood it treats any comma separated string values as a JsonArray, and uses Newtonsoft.JsonConvert to deserialize it into individual items.
In this case, if your variable contains CLIENTONE,CLIENTTWO,CLIENTTHREE then it will iterate over CLIENTONE CLIENTTWO and CLIENTTHREE as you'd expect.

#{each client in CLIENTS_QA} is considered the starting token of the variable expression.

This is important as it marks the index position of where the next characters should go.
That is why I have put #{each client in CLIENTS_QA}- name: #{USER_ENV}#{client} all into one line, without a newline separator. The current example from the Octopus doc is a little misleading because
Numbers:
#{each number in MyNumbers}
 - #{number}
#{/each}

would result in something like
Numbers:

 - 5

 - 2

 - 4


The extra newline before each item exists because there is a newline separating the starting token and the variable within the body of the expression. This can be a little gotcha, so it's worth keeping in mind.
Hope that helps.
